# Pandas - Group By and Cumulative Count Until The Value Changes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I want to take a cumulative count by `user` until the value in the column `events` changes. I am not able to quite figure it out how to do it.

**Data:** (You can assume that the data will be in chronological order)

```
user   events 
   a   no_event
   a   no_event
   a   aaa
   a   no_event
   a   bbb
   b   asdf
   b   no_event
   b   ghtu
```

**Desired Output:**

```
user   events    RN
   a   no_event  1
   a   no_event  2
   a   aaa       3
   a   no_event  1
   a   bbb       2
   b   asdf      1
   b   no_event  1
   b   ghtu      2
```

I appreciate your help. Also, is there a tutorial or a document where I can learn all different kinds of the conditional group by operations especially on the time series data?

Comment: check second answer `df1 = df.groupby(['user', 'events'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='event_count')`

Comment: Hey @jezrael - I have seen the solution on the link you provided but I don't think that is what I need. I have edited the question as I might have not framed the question correctly. Can you please re-open the question or try to answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper `Series` and pass to [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter:

```
m = df['events'].eq('no_event')
g = (m.ne(m.shift()) & m).cumsum()
df['RN2'] = df.groupby(['user', g]).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
  user    events  RN2
0    a  no_event    1
1    a  no_event    2
2    a       aaa    3
3    a  no_event    1
4    a       bbb    2
5    b      asdf    1
6    b  no_event    1
7    b      ghtu    2
```

**Explanation**:

1. First compare by `eq` with `no_event`
2. Then shift values
3. Compare for not equal
4. Chain with mask `m` for only `no_event` rows
5. Consecutive values by cumulative sum

```
print (df.assign(mask = df['events'].eq('no_event'),
                 shifted = m.shift(),
                 not_q = m.ne(m.shift()),
                 chained = (m.ne(m.shift()) & m),
                 consecut_gr = (m.ne(m.shift()) & m).cumsum()))

  user    events   mask shifted  not_q  chained  consecut_gr
0    a  no_event   True     NaN   True     True            1
1    a  no_event   True    True  False    False            1
2    a       aaa  False    True   True    False            1
3    a  no_event   True   False   True     True            2
4    a       bbb  False    True   True    False            2
5    b      asdf  False   False  False    False            2
6    b  no_event   True   False   True     True            3
7    b      ghtu  False    True   True    False            3
```

Still not 100% sure if necessary shift per groups, mainly it depends of data:

```
m = df['events'].eq('no_event')
g = (m.ne(m.groupby(df['user']).shift()) & m).cumsum()

df['RN'] = df.groupby(['user', g]).cumcount().add(1)
```

EDIT1: It is same:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000

L = ['no_event','a','s']
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': np.random.randint(100, size=N),
                   'events':np.random.choice(L,size=N)}).sort_values('user')

m = df['events'].eq('no_event')
g = (m.ne(m.shift()) & m).cumsum()
df['RN1'] = df.groupby(['user', g]).cumcount().add(1)

m = df['events'].eq('no_event')
g = (m.ne(m.groupby(df['user']).shift()) & m).cumsum()

df['RN2'] = df.groupby(['user', g]).cumcount().add(1)

print (df['RN2'].equals(df['RN1']))
True
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This is what I needed. I'm not able to understand what happening with `g = (m.ne(m.groupby(df['user']).shift()) & m).cumsum()`. Can you please explain? Also, is there a simpler solution than this? I'll accept this answer if not.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal - Working for explanation

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal - I have problem create data for simulate, if is possible simplify answer like main solution or is necessary solution in last paragraph. Can you test in real data if same output?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Your explanation is clear enough. I'm accepting your answer. Btw, thank you for introducing me to `pd.Series.ne`